# Still getting TypeError: .method takes (x) positional arguments but (x+1) were given, even though I have self in method definition

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to write a Python program which uses [websocket](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/) to get market stream data from cryptocurrency exchanges (Binance, Kraken, etc.)

Currently, I have an `Exchange` class as follows:

```
class Exchange(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__()
        self.web_socket = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            url = url,
            on_open = self.on_open,
            on_message = self.on_message,
            on_error = self.on_error,
            on_close = self.on_close
        )

    def on_open(self):
        pass

    def on_message(self, message):
        pass

    def on_error(self, error):
        pass
 
    def on_close(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.web_socket.run_forever()
```

I also have several other classes `Binance`, `Kraken`, and so on, which inherit from `Exchange`. They have their own implementations of the above methods. For example:

```
class Binance(Exchange):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__(url)

    def on_message(self, message):
        data = loads(message)
        ticker, price = data['s'][:3].lower(), data['p']
        print(f'{ticker}: ${price}')
```

My 'main.py' file:

```
binance_streams = 'btcusdt@trade/ethusdt@trade'
binance_url = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams={binance_streams}'

binance_client = Binance(binance_url)
binance_client.start()
```

After running, it should start printing statements like:

```
btc: $47950
eth: $3500
eth: $3501
btc: $47951
etc...
```

However, I get a TypeError for all of the `Exchange` methods, for example:

> Exchange.on_open() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
> Exchange.on_error() takes 2 positional arguments were 3 were given

I searched on StackOverflow for solutions, and it seems most errors were to do with `self` not being supplied in the method definition.

I have triple checked my code and made sure that `self` is indeed supplied in all my method definitions, however I'm still receiving this error.

I would appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: The method calls have additional arguments but the method definitions don't have matching parameters. Read the docs of "websocket.WebSocketApp" to find out which additional parameters the functions should have.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the reply. I found and looked at the websocket/_app.py documentation. It seems that my on_close was missing 2 arguments. I have added them now - def on_close(self, close_status_code, close_msg). However, the same error is still persisting. Could you see if anything is missing?

Comment: I forgot to mention that e. g. "self.on_open" is a so called "bound method". This means it is bound to the object "self" and when called automatically prepends it as first argument. So "self.on_open(a)" translates roughly to "Exchange.on_open(self, a)". So you have to add parameters for the missing arguments to the functions yet.

Comment: In the websocket/_app.py documentation, it says on_open has one argument which is "this class object". This class object means "self" right? My method definition is on_open(self). Or is "this class object" not equivalent to "self"? Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: It can't refer to "self" because the "WebSocketApp" doesn't even know if the constructor receives bound methods (with a "self") or simple functions without. The "class object" means the "WebSocketApp" object.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you Michael!

Comment: All your methods take one parameter too few. When the docs say "The 1st argument is this class object." it means an *instance of ``WebSocketApp``* is passed into the callback. That is separate from the ``self`` *instance of ``Exchange``*, which is passed in because your callbacks are also bound methods of ``Exchange``. It should be ``def on_open(self, app: WebSocketApp):`` instead of ``def on_open(self):``, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much MisterMiyagi. I finally got the class implementation working!

Comment: @bananastonk: note you can post (& accept) your own solution with explanation as an answer, which will help other users with the same problem.