# Can anyone provide me with working sample code for packaging Python websocket.WebSocketApp functionality in classes?

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to write a Python program which uses market stream data from various cryptocurrency exchanges. The aim is to collate the information to perform various actions. I would like to use the Python's `websocket.WebSocketApp` to obtain this market stream data. More specifically, I would like to package this functionality into my `Exchange` class, so that individual cryptocurrency exchanges such as `Binance`, `Kraken`, and so on, can inherit from it (as each exchange would require different implementations of the `websocket.WebSocketApp` method definitions.

I have tried to do this - here is a link to a previous post:

[Still getting TypeError: .method takes (x) positional arguments but (x+1) were given, even though I have self in method definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377184/still-getting-typeerror-method-takes-x-positional-arguments-but-x1-were-g)

I have also tried all the solutions in this post:

[Using a websocket client as a class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980966/using-a-websocket-client-as-a-class-in-python)

I'm having difficulty understanding what the error is - I would greatly appreciate if anyone could provide me with sample working code, or give me pointers in the right direction.

Comment: How exactly does the goal of this question differ from the previous?

Comment: I tried the solutions in the 2nd link after I couldn't figure out what was wrong with my solution (as referenced in the 1st link). They all end up with the same TypeError (takes 2 positional arguments, but 3 were given). I was hoping someone could provide a working solution, as none of those seem to work.

Comment: please post your code and the error you are getting, in addition to what you are expecting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.